# how can i passed array into a function in php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am thingking if i can pass arrays into a function in php, I mean as a parameter..
I know how to pass a variable like `function try($try) { }` but how can I accomplish if the variable to be pass is an array variable like,

```
$arrTry = array("name"=>"Keydi", "lname"=>"Paul");
```

Then,

```
function try($arrTry) { }
```

But the problem is that I do not know how could I get the value of the passed array inside the function..
My purpose is that i will make a function to get the table fieldnames then passed the result to a function that will make the sql statement for me,..,
Is there any way out??or do the long way,..,.,

Comment: Very poorly written question. I have absolutly no idea what you are trying to accomplish here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function search($arrTry)
{ 
  echo $arrTry["name"];
  echo '<br>';
  echo $arrTry["lname"];
}

  $arrTry = array("name"=>"Keydi", "lname"=>"Paul"); 


// To call this function
     search($arrTry);
```

Comment: @ArunKillu thanks for your comment. I have changed the function name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunc($arr)
{
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
//make your sql statements
}
}

//call this function like this
$arr = array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Keydi","class"=>"web development");
myfunc($arr);
```

Comment: this also gives syntax error

Comment: no need to share u have used "try" as func name before now you have edited answer its fine

Comment: oh yes. `try` is a keyword, my bad :(, and thanks @harmeet :)